# iOS 9 Auto-Layout and View Controllers; Knowing how to put the right constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to understand the basics of Auto Layout and have been trying to learn with no avail.  In the image I have below I have set no constraints as I always end up not doing it correctly.

For the four squares and buttons I just want them to show appropriately on all size classes and I can not get them to.  I always set leading constraints for the left squares/buttons and trailing constraints for the right squares/buttons(both to the main view controller).  I put horizontal spacing and vertical spacing between the squares/buttons and put bottom/top spacing on the bottom/top squares/buttons to the bottom/top layout guide.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all select your size class to for example w:compact h:regular and than do everything else.
You can do it using stack view. It is easy, just select two of your blue views (select one then hold shift and select second) and than click stack icon:

[image]

then set stack distribution to fill equally:

[image]

and set spacing for example to 8.:

[image]

than set constrains of the stack view to 0 from left and 0 from right and copy and paste. It will look like this:

[image]

then both stack view put in a stack view:

[image]

and set spacing to 8 in the main stack view.
Finally set 20 from bottom constraint to your main stack view.
You can use same way for buttons. After that you can simply set size class to all iPhones landscape (any,compact) and do same thing again.

If you do not understand anything, just ask me :).

Comment: First of all thank you for responding so quickly!  It seems as if I do it this way that the constraints work perfectly on all vertical size classes, however with horizontal size classes such as W:Compact H:Regular, it doesn't show appropriately.  What could I be doing wrong/is there a way to do it in all one size class such as W:Any H:Any?  Thanks!

Comment: It works just fine for me. Try doing all the steps again or post here some images how it works for you. I think that using size classes is the best way of doing this. (Don't know why but you are using just view not in stack view it work ok with :any :any)